# Spark - Finding overlapping values Or A variation of finding mutual friends

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, mapreduce, apache-spark-sql

I have a problem which I'm trying to solve using Spark. I'm fairly new to Spark so I am not sure what would be the best way to design it.

### Input:

```
group1=user1,user2
group2=user1,user2,user3
group3=user2,user4
group4=user1,user4
group5=user3,user5
group6=user3,user4,user5
group7=user2,user4
group8=user1,user5
group9=user2,user4,user5
group10=user4,user5
```

I want to find mutual group count between each pair of users. So for the above input, the output I'm expecting would be:

### Output:

```
1st user || 2nd user || mutual/intersection count || union count
------------------------------------------------------------
user1        user2           2                       7
user1        user3           1                       6
user1        user4           1                       9
user2        user4           3                       8
```

I think there are several ways to solve this problem, one of the solution could be:

- Create a key,value pair where key is user and value is group
- Group by key, then we will have a list of groups a user is belong to
- then find intersection/union between two groups

Example:

```
(1st stage): Map
group1=user1,user2 ==>
          user1, group1
          user2, group1
group2=user1,user2,user3 ==>
          user1, group2
          user2, group2
          user3, group2
....
....
....


(2nd stage): Reduce by key
user1 -> group1, group2, group4, group8
user2 -> group1, group2, group3, group7, group9
```

But my question is, what would be the best way to represent the count in the way I want after I reduce them by key?

Is there any better way to handle this problem? The maximum number of user is constant and will not go more than 5000, so that's the maximum number of keys it will create. But input may contains several lines close to 1B rows. I don't think that would be a problem, please correct me if I'm wrong.

### Update:

This is the piece of code I came up to solve this problem with my little knowledge of Spark (just started learning Spark last month):

```
def createPair(line: String): Array[(String, String)] = {
    val splits = line.split("=")
    val kuid = splits(0)
    splits(1).split(",").map { segment => (segment, kuid) }
}


val input = sc.textFile("input/test.log")
val pair = input.flatMap { line => createPair(line) }

val pairListDF = pair
  .aggregateByKey(scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.empty[String])(
    (kuidList, kuid) => { kuidList += kuid; kuidList },
    (kuidList1, kuidList2) => { kuidList1.appendAll(kuidList2); kuidList1 })
  .mapValues(_.toList).toDF().select($"_1".alias("user"), $"_2".alias("groups"))

pairListDF.registerTempTable("table")

sqlContext.udf.register("intersectCount", (list1: WrappedArray[String], list2: WrappedArray[String]) => list1.intersect(list2).size)
sqlContext.udf.register("unionCount", (list1: WrappedArray[String], list2: WrappedArray[String]) => list1.union(list2).distinct.size)

val populationDF = sqlContext.sql("SELECT t1.user AS user_first,"
  + "t2.user AS user_second,"
  + "intersectCount(t1.groups, t2.groups) AS intersect_count,"
  + "unionCount(t1.groups, t2.groups) AS union_count"
  + " FROM table t1 INNER JOIN table t2"
  + " ON t1.user < t2.user"
  + " ORDER BY user_first,user_second")
```

### Output:

```
+----------+-----------+---------------+-----------+
|user_first|user_second|intersect_count|union_count|
+----------+-----------+---------------+-----------+
|     user1|      user2|              2|          7|
|     user1|      user3|              1|          6|
|     user1|      user4|              1|          9|
|     user1|      user5|              1|          8|
|     user2|      user3|              1|          7|
|     user2|      user4|              3|          8|
|     user2|      user5|              1|          9|
|     user3|      user4|              1|          8|
|     user3|      user5|              2|          6|
|     user4|      user5|              3|          8|
+----------+-----------+---------------+-----------+
```

Would love to get some feedbacks about my code and things I'm missing. Please feel free to criticize my code as I just started learning Spark. Thanks again @axiom for your answer, much smaller and nicer solution than I expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summary:

Obtain pair counts, and then use the fact that

> union(a, b) = count(a) + count(b) - intersection(a, b)

```
val data = sc.textFile("test")
//optionally data.cache(), depending on size of data.
val pairCounts  = data.flatMap(pairs).reduceByKey(_ + _)
val singleCounts = data.flatMap(singles).reduceByKey(_ + _)
val singleCountMap = sc.broadcast(singleCounts.collectAsMap())
val result = pairCounts.map{case ((user1, user2), intersectionCount) =>(user1, user2, intersectionCount, singleCountMap.value(user1) + singleCountMap.value(user2) - intersectionCount)}
```

---

**Details:**

1. There are total 5000 users, 25 million keys (1 per pair) shouldn't be too much. We can use `reduceByKey` to calculate the intersection counts.
2. Individual counts can easily be `Broadcasted` in Maps.
3. And now the well known:

   `Union(user1, user2) = count(user1) + count(user2) - Intersection(user1, user2)`.

The first two counts are read from the broadcasted map, while we map over the rdd of pair counts.

Code:

```
//generate ((user1, user2), 1) for pair counts
def pairs(str: String) = {
 val users = str.split("=")(1).split(",")
 val n = users.length
 for(i <- 0 until n; j <- i + 1 until n) yield {
  val pair = if(users(i) < users(j)) {
    (users(i), users(j))
  } else {
   (users(j), users(i))
  } //order of the user in a list shouldn't matter
  (pair, 1)
 } 
}

//generate (user, 1), to obtain single counts
def singles(str: String) = {
  for(user <- str.split("=")(1).split(",")) yield (user, 1)
}


//read the rdd
scala> val data = sc.textFile("test")
scala> data.collect.map(println)
group1=user1,user2
group2=user1,user2,user3
group3=user2,user4
group4=user1,user4
group5=user3,user5
group6=user3,user4,user5
group7=user2,user4
group8=user1,user5
group9=user2,user4,user5
group10=user4,user5

//get the pair counts
scala> val pairCounts  = data.flatMap(pairs).reduceByKey(_ + _)
pairCounts: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[((String, String), Int)] = ShuffledRDD[16] at reduceByKey at <console>:25



//just checking
scala> pairCounts.collect.map(println)
((user2,user3),1)
((user1,user3),1)
((user3,user4),1)
((user2,user5),1)
((user1,user5),1)
((user2,user4),3)
((user4,user5),3)
((user1,user4),1)
((user3,user5),2)
((user1,user2),2)

//single counts
scala> val singleCounts = data.flatMap(singles).reduceByKey(_ + _)
singleCounts: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Int)] = ShuffledRDD[20] at reduceByKey at <console>:25

scala> singleCounts.collect.map(println)

(user5,5)
(user3,3)
(user1,4)
(user2,5)
(user4,6)


//broadcast single counts
scala> val singleCountMap = sc.broadcast(singleCounts.collectAsMap())

//calculate the results:
```

And finally:

```
scala> val res = pairCounts.map{case ((user1, user2), intersectionCount) => (user1, user2, intersectionCount, singleCountMap.value(user1) + singleCountMap.value(user2) - intersectionCount)}
res: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String, Int, Int)] = MapPartitionsRDD[23] at map at <console>:33

scala> res.collect.map(println)
(user2,user3,1,7)
(user1,user3,1,6)
(user3,user4,1,8)
(user2,user5,1,9)
(user1,user5,1,8)
(user2,user4,3,8)
(user4,user5,3,8)
(user1,user4,1,9)
(user3,user5,2,6)
(user1,user2,2,7)
```

---

Note:

1. While generating pairs, I sort the tuple because we don't want the order of users in a list to matter.
2. Do encode the username Strings to Integers, you may get significant performance boost.